# Getting an error using the WindowSetup class variable

Tags: c++, sfml

here is WindowSetup.h

```
class WindowSetup
{

public:

    WindowSetup();
    WindowSetup(const string& l_title ,Vector2u& l_size);
   ~WindowSetup();

}
```

Game.H

```
class Game
{
    Game();
   ~Game();

    WindowSetup m_window;
}
```

and the error is in Game.cpp

```
Game::Game():m_window("zzzzzz",Vector2u(800,600))
{


}
```

error :Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0289   no instance of constructor WindowSetup::WindowSetup matches the argument list

The argument list matches but still it gives error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add `const` to the arguments of the constructor:

```
WindowSetup(const string& l_title, const Vector2u& l_size);
```

`Vector2u(800,600)` is an r-value. You can't create a non-const reference of an r-value.

Comment: @LumbusterTick  In general all your reference parameters should be const unless you modify them inside the function.  A non const variable can be passed to a const parameter and so can an unnamed value (an r value) so there is no advantage to making the parameter non const unless you are going to modify it.

Comment: Ill make a note of that ty.